# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00905: object TEST.CMPPROJECTPROC is invalid\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, stored-procedures, plsql

I have created a procedure in oracle to insert data into table.When i call the procedure from asp.net webservices, its invoking the following error..

> "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00905: object TEST.CMPPROJECTPROC is invalid\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}"

My procedure code is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CMPPROJECTPROC (  
p_projectname CMPPROJECT.PROJECTNAME%TYPE,  
p_description CMPPROJECT.DESCRIPTION%TYPE,  
p_company CMPPROJECT.COMPANY%TYPE,
p_projectstatus CMPPROJECT.PROJECTSTATUS%TYPE,
p_websiteurl CMPPROJECT.WEBSITEURL%TYPE,
p_completedin CMPPROJECT.COMPLETEDIN%TYPE,
p_startedin CMPPROJECT.STARTEDIN%TYPE,
p_status CMPPROJECT.STATUS%TYPE)
IS  
BEGIN  
INSERT INTO CMPPROJECT (PROJECTNAME,DESCRIPTION,COMPANY,PROJECTSTATUS,WEBSITEURL,COMPLETEDIN,STARTEDIN,STATUS)  
VALUES (p_projectname,p_description,p_company,p_projectstatus,p_websiteurl,p_completedin,p_startedin,p_status);  
COMMIT;  
END;
```

My webservice code is

```
 [WebMethod]

        public void Insert(string name, string description, int companyName, int projectStatus, string websiteurl, string completedin, string startredin, int status)
        {
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            con.Open();

            //cmd.CommandText = "CMPPROJECTPROC";
            cmd = new OracleCommand("CMPPROJECTPROC", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_projectname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_description", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = description;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_company", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = companyName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_projectstatus", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = projectStatus;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_websiteurl", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = websiteurl;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_completedin", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = completedin;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_startedin", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = startredin;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("p_status", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = status;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: The stored procedure looks good to me, provided it resides in the same schema as table and column names in the table/procedure are spelled correctly. What's the output of `select * from all_errors ae where ae.name = 'CMPPROJECTPROC'`?

Comment: What IDE/tools are you using to write and compile your procedures? You need to investigate why the procedure is invalid. Normally your tools would make this pretty clear at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

The stored procedure in the database is invalid. It will have to be compiled again. It may throw errors.

A procedure will be invalidated, when anything changes in the database the procedure was compiled against. For example if you changed the table the procedure is using, it has to be recompiled or you will get this error message.

You can recompile your stored procedure by doing this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE TEST.CMPPROJECTPROC COMPILE;
```